# Guide for writing generic Java object mapper using reflection

Tags: java, reflection, mapping, persistence

I want to write a **generic mapper for Java objects**, which maps them into **another format**. Normally there are well designed solution, in this case however, the present solution is **not configurable whatsoever** and the output is not what I want.

I have already started writing my **home brew solution using Annotations and Java Reflection**. The problem is that I am noticing that there are many **edge cases**, for instance how to generically treat Enums, Collections, etc. All of this have to be considered and when you example data set does not cover all the edge cases it's not easy to find everything.

Is there something like a **guide** to find all **different types of Java types** which should be considered so that I don't miss something in the implementation?

Comment: I don't know about an official guide, but, if you seriously want to do this, study how other projects like XStream, Jackson, etc... (the list is large!) have done this and pick what feels best to you.

Comment: I don't think there is a guide as such, but if you look at the source code of XStream for example, it might be helpful. Actually, you might even be able to tweak XStream to produce the output you want.

Comment: Could you give an example what you would like to do?

Comment: [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/)

Comment: do you want to map and persist? or just transform from one object to another? in latter case - try http://dozer.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @Funtik I only want to map, I don't want a serialization where I can read the data in again. The output format is a text file.

Comment: how do you want to serialize it? should it be in human-readable format (xml or similar) inside the text file?